How can I save vimdiff output to a specific path in shell scripting
I have this shell script line to save vimdiff output in html format
vimdiff -c TOhtml -c 'w! diff.html | qa!' $INITIAL_FILE $FINAL_FILE
But this saves the file in the same directory as the shell script. How can I pass a specific path for the diff.html file here?
I tried something like this
vimdiff -c TOhtml -c 'w! $SAVE_PATH | qa!' $INITIAL_FILE $FINAL_FILE
But it just gives a file with the name $SAVE_PATH. Are there any work arounds for this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

You need to use double quotes instead of singles. Bash will only substitute variables in double quotes. See man bash.

When using single quotes, you beg the shell to not substitute the variable.
